# Initialize member variable without making a new copy

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I have a class that needs to know about some large data structure. Therefore, I created a constructor that accepts a reference to that large data structure and uses it to initialize a member variable like so:

```
 class Foo {
 public:
   BigStruct m_bigstruct;

   Foo(BigStruct &inBigStruct) : m_bigstruct(inBigStruct) {}
 };
```

This appears to make a copy of `inBigStruct`, but I don't want to waste those resources because `BigStruct`s are huge. Is there a more standard way of making the contents of `inBigStruct` available to Foo without copying it? I know I can do this:

```
 class Foo {
 public:
   BigStruct* m_bigstruct;

   Foo(BigStruct* inBigStruct) : m_bigstruct(inBigStruct) {}
 };
```

Is this the usual way to make `inBigStruct` available to `Foo` without copying? If not, what is?

Comment: You can also hold a reference to `Bigstruct`.

Comment: Before c++11 there's no way built into the language of knowing when it is safe to steal from another object. I guess you could write a `steal(BigStruct& other)` function. With c++11 you write a move constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx

Comment: @BoBTFish: the usual idiom in C++03 is to implement and use `swap` rather than a function named `steal`. Amounts to much the same thing, though: the caller figures out whether it's OK to mess with the original.

Comment: Since we broached C++11, I should point out that I solved the true problem--a functor--in C++11 easily by using a lambda. No copy necessary with capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may store reference if you are sure that it'll not invalidated while Foo is alive.

```
class Foo {
 public:
   /*const*/ BigStruct& m_bigstruct;

   Foo(BigStruct &inBigStruct) : m_bigstruct(inBigStruct) {}
 };
```

Comment: @BoBTFish, I don't think so.

Comment: @BoBTFish Maybe not better, but expressing a different intent: the member refers to one and only one object during its lifetime.

Comment: This seems like simultaneously the most logical thing to do and the most dangerous. I literally just want a reference to inBigStruct, but I also cannot guarantee something won't invalidate the instance to which inBigStruct refers in the meantime. Of course, if the original becomes invalidated for any reason, there's also not much point in continuing anyway...

Comment: @Fadecomic, If somebody can destroy original object, you have to have copy to work. You can also think about `shared_ptr` btw

Answer (score 3):

The C++2011 approach is to move objects, e.g.:

```
Foo::Foo(BigStruct const& argument): m_bigstruct(argument) {}       // copies
Foo::Foo(BigStruct&& argument): m_bigstruct(std::move(argument)) {} // moves
```

Of course, this assumes that `BigStruct` has a suitable move constructor. Depending on whether a temporary (or something looking like a temporary by way of `std::move()`) or a lvalue is passed, the object will get moved or copied: If you have another reference to an object, you generally don't want to steal the object but copy it.